# Tomcat not starting with `tomcat start/post-stop`

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, tomcat

I'm trying to install and run tomcat 8 on the remote Ubuntu 14.04 as per the instructions on [this post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04).

My `tomcat.conf` file is as follows:
description "Tomcat Server"

```
  start on runlevel [2345]
  stop on runlevel [!2345]
  respawn
  respawn limit 10 5

  setuid tomcat
  setgid tomcat

  env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
  env CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat

  # Modify these options as needed
  env JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"
  env CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms256M -Xmx512M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

  exec $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run

  # cleanup temp directory after stop
  post-stop script
    rm -rf $CATALINA_HOME/temp/*
  end script
```

After saving I ran `sudo initctl reload-configuration` and then `sudo initctl start tomcat` but I get the message:

`tomcat start/post-stop, process 1259`

Obviously tomcat is not started and when I run `sudo initctl status tomcat` I get the message :

`tomcat stop/waiting`

What am I missing?

Comment: i am having the same problem currently , can you tell me how you got a fix then . The below answer didn't help me out

Answer (score 1):

It might be permission issue, check in /var/log/upstart/tomcat.log, you may find this log:

```
/bin/sh: 1: exec: /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: Permission denied
```

To fix all these permission issues, do this:

```
sudo chown -R tomcat:tomcat /opt/tomcat
```